# JWT Authentication user_not_found Tymon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, json-web-token

I have set up Tymon Package for JWT Authentication.  In case of new user sign up or login I get the token successfully.  But when I pass the token to the Laravel JWT I get an error as user not found.

controller code

```
public function authenticate()
    {
        $credentials = request()->only('user_name','password');
        try{
            $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
            if(!$token){
                return response()->json(['error'=>'invalid_credentials'],401);
            }
        }
        catch(JWTException $e){
            return response()->json(['error'=>'something went wrong'],500);
        }
        return response()->json(['token'=>$token],200);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $user_name = request()->user_name;
        $c_name = request()->company_name;
        $accessibility_level = request()->accessability_level;
        $password = request()->password;
        $contact_number = request()->contact_number;
        $address = request()->address;

        $user = User::create([
            'user_name'=>$user_name,
            'c_name'=>$c_name,
            'accessibility_level'=>$accessibility_level,
            'password'=>bcrypt($password),
            'contact_number'=>$contact_number,
            'address'=>$address
        ]);

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

        return response()->json(['token'=>$token],200);
    }
```

no problem with the above code works fine.

But when I try to access some data with JWT validation I get an error as USER_NOT_FOUND.  I have passed the Token which I have got as an header through Postman.

Route Code

```
Route::get('/some_route','some_controller@index')->middleware('jwt.auth');
```

And the jwt.php is also set with the correct identifier which I have used in the model(Primary key)

```
'identifier' => 'user_name',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT identifier doesn't work by simply modifying the config because it's [hardcoded](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/master/src/JWTAuth.php#L44) as id in the code for some reason

You can of course use the `setIdentifier` method before calling any other JWTAuth methods to set the identifier.

Here's how:

```
public function authenticate()
    {
        $credentials = request()->only('user_name','password');
        try{
            $token = JWTAuth::setIdentifier('user_name')->attempt($credentials);
            if(!$token){
                return response()->json(['error'=>'invalid_credentials'],401);
            }
        }
        catch(JWTException $e){
            return response()->json(['error'=>'something went wrong'],500);
        }
        return response()->json(['token'=>$token],200);
    }
```

Then create a custom middleware for jwt authentication:

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $token = $this->auth->setIdentifier('user_name')->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
        }

        try {
            $user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.expired', 'token_expired', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.invalid', 'token_invalid', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
        }

        if (! $user) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.user_not_found', 'user_not_found', 404);
        }

        $this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);

        return $next($request);
    }
```